# undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Faced with such a problem. Please tell me why this is happening?

```
    NoMethodError in Searches#index

undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #14):

11: </div>
12: <div class="results">
13: <table>
14: <% @searches.each do |search, book| %>
15:   <tr>
16:     <% if session[:user_id] %>
17:     <td><%= search.name %></td>
```

Comment: @searches should look like [ [search, book], [search, book], ...] to work with such iteration, as far as I know.

Comment: can you please post the controller methods as well

Comment: @searches is probably nil.  Try this to check

Comment: If @searches was nill, it would be 'undefined method 'each' for nil'.

Comment: I think your @searches is just one-dimensional array, this way running |variable1, variable2| returns this kind of error, because than variable2 is assigned to nil. Just checked this in console. Can you please remove loop, output '@searches.inspect' and post what it look like in question editing.

Comment: Thanks for all the help I understood where I made ​​a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@searches is probably nil. Change this

```
<% @searches.each do |search, book| %>
...
<% end %>
```

To this:

```
<% if !@searches %>
<h1> @searches is nil </h1>
<% else %>
 @searches.each do |search, book| 
%>
....
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

This will tell you if @searches is nil.

Comment: You were right. All my data is in production and not of development. Site on the local machine worked well, but as I put the server's had such an error. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I can't explain why calling .each on a nil class tells you that '<' isn't defined for that class, it would make more sense if it told you '.each' isn't defined.   Maybe someone who knows more about the internals of ruby/rails can explain this

Comment: This problem does not rails it is a problem in the intricacies of setting the sphinx and thinking sphinx, because the other views are working well.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<%= search['name'] %>
```

instead of using this:

```
<%= search.name %>
```